# Confusing C++ Assignment

Tags: c++

I'm a freshman college CS student, and I can't seem to figure this problem out. It basically wants me to ask the user for the amount of students in a particular class, and then continuously loop asking for the students names. After all that is done, I have to find out which name that was entered will be first, alphabetically, and which name will be last, alphabetically.

My code so far does everything up until I have to sort through the names, as well as displaying the names incorrectly. It only displays the latest name entered, not both names at once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int studentCount;
    string studentName;

    cout << "Hello fellow educator!" << endl;
    cout << "I will be helping you with your line-up for today." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of students in your class: ";
    cin >> studentCount;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    if (studentCount < 1 || studentCount > 25) {
        cout << "Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "Try putting in a number between 1 and 25." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int count = 1; count <= studentCount; count++) {

        cout << "Please enter a student's name: ";
        cin >> studentName;
    }
    cout << "the names are " << studentName; // Just testing the string

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to store each name somewhere after reading it in.

Comment: Compile with *all warnings & debug info* (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and *use the debugger* (`gdb`) to run your program step by step.

Comment: Actually you don't need to store all the names. Just store the current one, and the alphabetically first and last ones, and you're done. No need to sort, that way!

Comment: @cliffordheath The assignment calls to have a list of 1-25 names, given by the user, and then to sort through those names and find the alphabetical first and last in the set of (what my professor will probably try) 25 names.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you need to make an array of `string` instead of a single string to avoid overwriting.
2. After that, **sort** them `lexicographically` and print them.

#### EDIT:

Have a look at the code given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>      /* Used to sort the string lexicographically */
#define LIMIT 50          /* I'm considering that you are not providing more than 50
                             names at once to a program*/
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int studentCount;              /* Count number of the students */
    string studentName[LIMIT];     /* Array of string */

    cin >> studentCount;           /* Input number of student */

    /* Keep on asking until the correct value of studentCount is not provided */
    while (studentCount < 1 || studentCount > 25) {  
        cout << "Please try again." << endl;  
        cout << "Try putting in a number between 1 and 25." << endl;
        cin >> studentCount;
    }
    
    cout <<"Please enter a student's name: ";
    for (int count = 0; count < studentCount; count++) {  
        cin >> studentName[count];        /* I started the count value from 0 to n-1 
                                          because the index of an array starts from 0 */ 
    }
    
    /* Now, time to sort the array of string lexicographically */
    sort(studentName, studentName+studentCount);
    
    /* Print the names of the student */
    cout << "Names of the students : " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i< studentCount; i++) {
        cout << studentName[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code will keep on asking until correct value of `studentCount` is **not** received. You can even change the upper limit of the program by changing the value of `LIMIT` from `50` to something else you may need.

Comment: I haven't gotten to array's and vectors yet.. Looking online, using an array is almost the same as Java. (I've taken a high school class revolving around Java, don't remember much though).

So to do this, I would have to do:

string studentNames [studentCount]; ...?

Comment: @AndrewMiller Finally. what you need **Code** for it or better explanation.

Comment: it tells me the studentCount needs to be constant, and that won't ever be constant.

Comment: no it is not necessary. even you could dynamically allocate the memory as much as you require. But first you need to take **studentCount** as an input and then accordinglly allocate the memory to it. and do the same as explained above

Comment: I'd like to see some code if at all possible. Literally been on this for an hour now.

Answer (score 1):

As you collect names, Store the names in a data structure.If you keep adding all names to a single string, then, it can be stored as one concatenated string but we want different names(strings).
So, Lets take vector as our datastructure.

```
int main () {

int studentCount;
string studentName;
vector<string> attendanceBook;

for (int count = 1; count <= studentCount; count++) {

    cout << "Please enter a student's name: ";
    studentName.clear();
    cin >> studentName;
    attendanceBook.push_back(studentName);
}

std::sort(attendanceBook.begin(),attendanceBook.end());

cout<<"First: "<<name.front<<endl<<"Last: "<<name.back();
```

Comment: I haven't learned vectors or arrays or anything like that yet, so is there a way to do this assignment without the use of arrays, vectors, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

So this is the completed code, after hours of work, and it runs and does everything properly. It's simple, I know, but to a college freshman only having been exposed to the surface of Java, this is complicated to me. :) I knew there was a way of doing this without vectors or arrays.. Thanks to everyone who tried their best to help me. I'll be sure to come back in the future.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main () {

        int studentCount;
        string studentNames;
        string first;
        string last;

        cout << "Hello fellow educator!" << endl;
        cout << "I will be helping you with your line-up for today." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number of students in your class: ";
        cin >> studentCount;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;

        while (studentCount < 1 || studentCount > 25) {
            cout << "Please try again." << endl;
            cout << "Try putting in a number between 1 and 25: ";
            cin >> studentCount;
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < studentCount; count++) {

            cout << "Please enter the name for student number " << count + 1 << ":";
            cin >> studentNames;

            if (count == 1) {

                first = studentNames;
                last = studentNames;

            }
            else {
                if (studentNames < first) {
                first = studentNames;
            }
                else if (studentNames > last) {
                    last = studentNames;
                }
            }
        }

            cout << "The first student in line is " << first << "." << endl;
            cout << "The last student in line is  " << last << "." << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted because I like the approach of a student posting his result after posting a question and receiving some help.